# Can you display voltage vs. time for a 5 Hz non-periodic signal with an oscilliscope?

Tags: voltage, oscilloscope

I have no first hand experience with oscilloscopes. I want to visually see the voltage history over 10 second intervals continuously sampled between 5 and 10 Hz (either is fine, as long as it's a steady sample rate). The X axis is scrolling (updating) time of 10 seconds, Y axis is measuring a non-periodic DC voltage ranging between -10V to +10V with auto-scale Y axis to accommodate low voltage readings in the 0.01 V range.

Is this possible with the typical handheld oscilloscopes in the $100 range? For example the Hantek 2C42, or any other equivalent oscilloscope?

Update:
Yes there is a scrolling time axis on this particular oscilloscope. I purchased the scope based on the comments and have experimented. The "Time" menu has a feature called "Roll" which scrolls the x-axis right to left based on the increment specified; 0.5 seconds per division, 1s, 2s, 5 s, etc...the scale is very wide for long term measurements. The y axis is adjustable as well, although I'm not sure what the sample rate is, but it's very fast (much faster than my needs require). Thanks everyone for the input!

Comment: use `single sweep` function

Comment: Sometimes labeled as just 'Single'.  It is still possible to use 'Normal' mode, but the display will update on each new trigger.  *** DO NOT USE AUTO mode *** (AUTO mode should be outlawed, IMHO), or the scope will trigger somewhat randomly.  If you are using a separate trigger input, it's a good idea to display that trigger input as well, to visually confirm your intentions.  Good luck!

Comment: Almost any modern digital scope can display signals with a 1 second/div sweep speed. However the y axis setting will not change during this sweep. For a range of +10V to -10V, a suitable vertical setting is either 2 volt/div or 5 volts/div. What do you mean by autoscale with a 0.01 volt range? At 2 or 5 volts/div, you cannot resolve 0.01 volts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you want to know whether the oscilloscope can do this before you spend the money on one.

Yes, this is generally possible on any oscilloscope. I can't speak specifically about the Hantek 2C42. It would be rather strange if one *couldn't* do what you're asking. I suppose that perhaps some oscilloscopes designed for very fast signals might not have an X-axis setting that is slow enough.

Looking at the [Hantek 2000-series manual](https://www.pinsonne-elektronik.de/media/daten/Hantek2000%20Series%20Handheld%20Scopemeter%20Manual_EN%20V1.4.pdf), under "Horizontal System" it speaks of having "roll mode" and "scan mode" for low-frequency signals (100ms/division or more). Although I couldn't see whether it specifically has a 10-second (1sec/division) as the manual didn't list the settings, it wouldn't make sense for them to have these features, if they had not though about displaying long periods of time.

Comment: side note, I had no idea they made handheld function generator/oscilloscopes, and I may have to get one